# Don't understand how paddle location is tracked; using XNA tutorial

Tags: monogame

Wanting to learn how to make games, decided to use Monogame. Have pretty light programming knowledge, so I apologize beforehand for my ignorance to this surely obvious oversight.

Following a beginner's tutorial on XNA game development. It's a simple ball and paddle game that has a game class, paddle class, and ball class.

Now my problem lies in the code for the ball class.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

    namespace BreakingOut
{
class Ball
{
    Vector2 motion;
    Vector2 position;
    float ballSpeed = 4;

    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle screenBounds;

    public Ball(Texture2D texture, Rectangle screenBounds)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.screenBounds = screenBounds;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        position += motion * ballSpeed;
        CheckWallCollision();
    }

    private void CheckWallCollision()
    {
        if (position.X < 0)
        {
            position.X = 0;
            motion.X *= -1;
        }
        if (position.X + texture.Width > screenBounds.Width)
        {
            position.X = screenBounds.Width - texture.Width;
            motion.X *= -1;
        }
        if (position.Y < 0)
        {
            position.Y = 0;
            motion.Y *= -1;
        }
    }

    public void SetInStartPosition(Rectangle paddleLocation)
    {
        motion = new Vector2(1, -1);
        position.Y = paddleLocation.Y - texture.Height;
        position.X = paddleLocation.X + (paddleLocation.Width - texture.Width) / 2;
    }

    public bool OffBottom()
    {
        if (position.Y > screenBounds.Height)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void PaddleCollision(Rectangle paddleLocation)
    {
        Rectangle ballLocation = new Rectangle(
            (int)position.X,
            (int)position.Y,
            texture.Width,
            texture.Height);

        if (paddleLocation.Intersects(ballLocation))
        {
            position.Y = paddleLocation.Y - texture.Height;
            motion.Y *= -1;
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
    }
}
}
```

When I run the game, it functions properly. Player moves the paddle, and when the ball collides with the paddle, it bounces off.  I don't understand how the Ball class knows the paddle location though.  It's not like paddleLocation is a public variable in the paddle class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position is actually stored in `Vector2 position;`

The reason it is accesible without `public` is because it is modified within the class. The three access modifiers are `public` `private` `protected` and `Vector2 position` by default is `private`

I suggest you learn C# first before delving into XNA to not have problems like these.

Comment: Thanks for helping, and learning more C# first is an excellent suggestion I will definitely follow. But for now, ,this problem is sitll driving me crazy because I think in this class, Vector2 position is holding the X and Y coordinates of the ball, not the paddle.

The SetInStartPosition function takes Rectangle paddleLocation as an argument, but I don't quite understand because the positions in this function are self-referencing to a rectangle that was never defined before.

I'm sorry, but could you point out to me where in the code the paddle location is stored? This is driving me crazy

Comment: @user83858 in the paddle class

Comment: @user83858 also of my answered helped you out, you can always ticket the empty check mark to mark my answer as your wanted answer

Comment: I will, just one more question. Looking back through the paddle class I don't see anything referred to as paddleLocation, so I'm still confused as to how the ball class is getting the information from the paddle class on the paddle's location.

Comment: @user83858 both paddle and ball class contain the `Vector2 position;` field which holds the position

Comment: Paddle location is just a placeholder in the function for the actual location, it is a parameter

Comment: Well thanks for your help, I think I kind of understand now. Definitely going to go learn more C#.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it's also an old problem that most new programmers run into at some point. Thought I'd give it a more extensive answer.

Assuming you wrote as the tutorial wrote, You'll have this function in your ball class. Note that it's a public function, which means that it can be accessed outside the class. Secondly it takes the paddleLocation as an argument, meaning when this function is called it requires a Rectangle to be passed along with it.

```
public void PaddleCollision(Rectangle paddleLocation)
{
   Rectangle ballLocation = new Rectangle(
   (int)position.X,
   (int)position.Y,
   texture.Width,
   texture.Height);
   if (paddleLocation.Intersects(ballLocation))
   {
     position.Y = paddleLocation.Y - texture.Height;
     motion.Y *= -1;
   }
}
```

That is how you ball class knows of the paddleLocation. In Game1 update there is a function call to the ball class

```
ball.PaddleCollision(paddle.GetBounds());
```

Which does just that. Each time this line gets called it will pass the rectangle bounds to the PaddleCollision funtion in your ball class.

It can do this because there is a GetBounds function in the paddle class.

```
public Rectangle GetBounds()
{
   return new Rectangle(
   (int)position.X,
   (int)position.Y,
   texture.Width,
   texture.Height);
}
```

The ball class knows nothing of the paddle class, vice versa, but the game1 class initiates both of them, so it knows of them both. Which is why it can access the public functions in both of them.

This is a fairly common way to pass data around, hope this cleared it up for anyone with a similar problem.